# Convert array of bytes to string then back it to array of bytes again

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java, I have array of bytes that I need to convert to string.
After that I want to change it back from string to array of bytes.
I tried the code below, but it did not work since the return value from line 2 does not match the original array:

```
byte[] comData = byteArray;
String value = new String(comData);
byte[] comData2 = value.getBytes();
// comData2 does not equal comData
```

Comment: :) this is just a sample explains how I convert it ,for sure comData will be not available in the real case :)

Comment: How are you comparing the two arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is an *arbitrary* collection of bytes, i.e. it isn't *actually* encoded text, then I'd recommend you use base64. There's a [public domain library available](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) which makes it easy (or various other third party libraries).

Sample code:

```
byte[] originalData = ...
String base64 = Base64.encode(myByteArray);
byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(base64);
```

Your original code assumes that the data represents text encoded in the platform default encoding. You should almost always *avoid* using the platform default encoding - if you *do* want to use a text encoding, it's usually better to specify one, e.g.

```
byte[] encodedText = text.getBytes("utf-8");
```

(Of course, if you're *decoding* the binary data, then you can't choose the encoding - you need to *know* which encoding to use.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd that the returned array does not match the original. However, there may be some subtle character encoding issue. Try specifying an explicit encoding for the bytes, e.g.:

```
byte[] comData = byteArray;
String value = new String(comData, "UTF-8");
byte[] comData2 = value.getBytes("UTF-8");

System.out.println(Arrays.equals(comData, comData2) ? "Success" : "Failure");
```

Since you say you are a beginner in Java, it's worth noting that you cannot compare the two arrays using `==` or `.equals()`. Both of those test whether the arrays are the same object, not whether they have the same contents.

Comment: Specifying UTF-8 if it *isn't* UTF-8 encoded data is a bad idea. There are plenty of byte sequences which simply aren't valid UTF-8.

Comment: @JonSkeet UTF-8 was by way of example, and OP should use whatever encoding is relevant for the data. Of course, if the bytes aren't character data at all, then encoding the bytes using something like base 64 (as you suggested in your answer) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

try it so:

```
byte[] comData = byteArray;
String value = new String();
for(byte me : comData)
{
    value += (char)me;
}
byte[] comData2;
{
    List<byte> temp;
    for(int i=0; i<value.size(); i++)//it may be value.length(), I don't remember
    {
        temp.add(byte(value.getChar(i)));
    }
}
comData2 = temp.getArray();
}
```

The main problem you're encountering is that you try to use the byte values as the constructor... and then convert the STRING to bytes.
You should convert it to char and back using simple casting, in that case it will be the same 0 and 1s.

***NOTE*** some names may vary as I don't keep all of the Java API in my head ;)

Comment: There is not necessarily a 1-1 correspondence between bytes and characters.

Comment: Yes, but casting it directly will keep it intact, the goal isn't to print the string, but to save it inside a string temporarily.

Comment: If the goal is indeed to print out the string then Base64 is the way to go.

Comment: OP hasn't said why the bytes need to be converted to a String.

Comment: True, but he doesn't seem to be doing anything with it, at may just as well be simply encoding/decoding it. In that case casting is more efficient.

Comment: @Shingetsu: This is generally a bad idea (and you're doing it very inefficiently, too). Requests like this are usually in a situation where the text needs to be transmitted - in which case having unprintable characters is a recipe for disaster.